# How to compare AD null property against CSV empty property

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a question like in the subject - How to compare an AD null property against a CSV empty property?

I update users AD account properties with values imported from CSV file.
Problem occurs when the property value is not specified in CSV - is empty.
For example let it be a City property.

For the first AD update, after property value change occured in CSV, I use **`Set-AdUser -Clear l`** because it seems that Replace option doesn't work for empty value. It makes property value $null in AD.

When I run script for the second time the properties in AD and CSV are still recognized as unequal by this comparison - `($UserWzor.City -ne $UserAD.l)`.
It causes the comparison for all properties at once fails -

```
if (($(($UserAD.sAMAccountName).length) -eq 4) -and (($UserWzor.Surname -ne ($UserAD.sn -replace '[ ]\d+$')) -or ($UserWzor.GivenName -ne $UserAD.GivenName) -or ($UserWzor.City -ne $UserAD.l) -or ($UserWzor.Title -ne $UserAD.Title) -or ($UserWzor.Company -ne $UserAD.Company) -or ($UserWzor.Department -ne $UserAD.Department) -or ($UserWzor.StreetAddress -ne $UserAD.StreetAddress) -or ($UserWzor.Office -ne $UserAD.Office) -or ($UserWzor.OfficePhone -ne $UserAD.OfficePhone) -or ($UserWzor.Manager -ne $Manager.sAMAccountName))){
    PorownajIZmienWartosc -Konto $UserAD.sAMAccountName -WlasciwoscLDAP 'Surname' -MaByc $UserWzor.Surname -Jest ($UserAD.sn -replace '[ ]\d+$') -WlasciwoscAD Surname
    PorownajIZmienWartosc -Konto $UserAD.sAMAccountName -WlasciwoscLDAP 'GivenName' -MaByc $UserWzor.GivenName -Jest $UserAD.GivenName -WlasciwoscAD GivenName
    PorownajIZmienWartosc -Konto $UserAD.sAMAccountName -WlasciwoscLDAP 'Title' -MaByc $UserWzor.Title -Jest $UserAD.Title -WlasciwoscAD Title
    PorownajIZmienWartosc -Konto $UserAD.sAMAccountName -WlasciwoscLDAP 'Company' -MaByc $UserWzor.Company -Jest $UserAD.Company -WlasciwoscAD Company
    PorownajIZmienWartosc -Konto $UserAD.sAMAccountName -WlasciwoscLDAP 'Department' -MaByc $UserWzor.Department -Jest $UserAD.Department -WlasciwoscAD Department
    PorownajIZmienWartosc -Konto $UserAD.sAMAccountName -WlasciwoscLDAP 'City' -MaByc $UserWzor.City -Jest $UserAD.l -WlasciwoscAD l
    PorownajIZmienWartosc -Konto $UserAD.sAMAccountName -WlasciwoscLDAP 'StreetAddress' -MaByc $UserWzor.StreetAddress -Jest $UserAD.StreetAddress -WlasciwoscAD StreetAddress
    PorownajIZmienWartosc -Konto $UserAD.sAMAccountName -WlasciwoscLDAP 'Office' -MaByc $UserWzor.Office -Jest $UserAD.Office -WlasciwoscAD physicalDeliveryOfficeName
    PorownajIZmienWartosc -Konto $UserAD.sAMAccountName -WlasciwoscLDAP 'OfficePhone' -MaByc $UserWzor.OfficePhone -Jest $UserAD.OfficePhone -WlasciwoscAD telephoneNumber
    PorownajIZmienWartosc -Konto $UserAD.sAMAccountName -WlasciwoscLDAP 'Manager' -MaByc $UserWzor.Manager -Jest $Manager.sAMAccountName -WlasciwoscAD Manager
}
```

and I have to check every one property seperately.
Empty values in CSV file can occur for multiple properties.

Should I put check for $null and blank values for every one property in this one line *if* statement?

I've written a function to make changes in AD. It recognizes that values are the same and finally don't try to change AD. Code for this is shown below (where $MaByc is the value from CSV and $Jest is the AD property value).

```
function PorownajIZmienWartosc ($Konto, $WlasciwoscLDAP, $WlasciwoscAD, $MaByc, $Jest) {
if (($MaByc -ne $Jest) -and (!((($MaByc -eq $null) -or ($MaByc -eq "")) -and (($Jest -eq $null) -or ($Jest -eq ""))))) {
    if (($MaByc -eq $null) -or ($MaByc -eq "") -or ($MaByc.length -lt 1)) {
        Set-ADUser -Identity $Konto -PassThru -Server $DC -Clear $WlasciwoscAD #-WhatIf
    }
    elseif ($WlasciwoscLDAP -eq "Manager" -and $MaByc.length -eq 4) {
        $Szef = Get-ADUser -Filter "sAMAccountName -eq '$MaByc'" -Server $DC -SearchBase $SzukajOd
        Set-ADUser -Identity $Konto -PassThru -Server $DC -Manager $Szef #-WhatIf
    }
    else {
        try {
            Set-ADUser -Identity $UserWzor.sAMAccountName -PassThru -Server $DC -Replace @{ $WlasciwoscLDAP = $MaByc } #-WhatIf
        }
        catch {
            "  -  Blad Set-ADUser" | Out-File $Bledy -Encoding UTF8 -Append -Force -NoNewline
        }
    }
    "`r`n" | Out-File $Bledy -Encoding UTF8 -Append -Force
}
```

I try to replace empty values from CSV with $null - `if (($Linia.City).length -lt 1){ $Linia.City = $null }` - but with no effect (*$Linia* is a single line in CSV file).

When I debug the script I can see in debugger Variables window that AD property value is $null when CSV property value is still blank. Debugger Watch window shows both as (Empty). Other values also look identical (except they might be written in upper- and lower cases differently).

Comment: Why not just replace `$null` with empty string? `if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Jest)) {$Jest = ""}`? Or to check both: `if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Jest) -and [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($MaByc)) { do something}`. Of course all in `PorownajIZmienWartosc`.

Comment: But it makes no major improvement over existing solution.t's still in function which is called to check for every proprty value change after main check detect any values differency between AD and CSV.

Comment: In that case you could just write a function which do some basic equality check and use it instead of `-ne`. That'd be the easiest approach I think.